# Javascript function defined in <head> is not being called on S3

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, amazon-web-services

I have a .json file in a bucket on S3. I'm trying to parse information from the file, a date and a SigninSim. I am doing this through an html file which once I get this figured out will take that parsed information, go into another folder, and display some pictures. Here is the code that I currently have written.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/'BUCKET'/browser.json"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function parseJSON()
            {
                var info = JSON.parse(browser);
                document.write(info.date);
                document.write(info.SigninSim);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            parseJSON();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this nothing shows up on the page. Any ideas? I'm also very new to html/javascript so I could be doing something completely wrong, anything helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<script>` tags can only be used to execute Javascript code, not to read JSON files.

Change the JSON file to a Javascript file that creates global variables or objects.

Comment: Is there any way to go about this with keeping it as a JSON file?

Comment: @KLime: You can use AJAX to read the file.  Beware of asynchrony and SOP.